# test-wsman works but enter-pssession fails

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

I am trying to open a remote powershell session on server2 from server1(both of them in the same domain). When I try to run the following command from server1:

`Enter-pssession -computername server2 -Credential $cred`

I get the following error:

```
Enter-pssession : Connecting to remote server server2 failed with the following error message : The WSMan service 
could not launch a host process to process the given request. Make sure the WSMan provider host server and proxy are 
properly registered. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (server2:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

But running the test-wsman command gives:

```
Test-WSMan -ComputerName server2 -Credential $cred -Authentication Kerberos

wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 10.0.17763 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0
```

Can't figure out the issue. Have tried Enable-PSRemoting and checked $PSSessionOption for proxy.

Comment: try stopping and starting winrm manually

Comment: Does [this](https://softwarealliance.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/22000243674-the-wsman-service-could-not-load-host-process-error) help?